# Topology on the Set of Convergent Sequences

Tags: general-topology

I'm a beginner in topology and I got stuck at solving the problem below.

Let $X$ be the set of all convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ be the set of all sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ whose sum converges. In other words,
\begin{equation}
X=\{\{a_n\}\,|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n\; \text{converges},\, a_n\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}\\
Y=\{\{b_n\}\,|\textstyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n\; \text{converges},\, b_n\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}.
\end{equation}
For each $L\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, define $B_{L,\,\epsilon}=\{\{c_n\}\in X\,|\,L-\epsilon<\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}c_n<L+\epsilon\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{B_{L,\,\epsilon}\,|\,L\in \mathbb{R},\,\epsilon>0\}$.
Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$ and find the closure $\bar{Y}$.

I can prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology on $X$ but I failed to prove the next one. I tried to get $A'$, the set of limit points of $A$, to obtain $\bar{A}$ by using $\bar{A}=A\cup A'$. But it is confusing for me to deal with the space of sequences, such as an open set whose elements are sequences. Can somebody tell me how should I approach this problem?

Comment: If $\{b_n\} \in Y$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$. If anything, $Y$ is a subset of the set of all sequences that converge to zero. Now, can you show that this is closed (or, it's complement is open) under the given topology on $X$? We can later see why it's also the smallest closed set.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you for your helpful hint!

Answer (score 1):

Let $L: X \to \mathbb{R}$ the function that sends every sequence to it limit, where the reals have the their usual topology.

The topology on $X$ is now the smallest topology on $X$ that makes $L$ continuous, the so-called initial topology w.r.t. $L$. This means that the topology on $X$ is just given by $\{L^{-1}[O]: O \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ open }\}$ and thus the closed sets are of the form $X\setminus L^{-1}[O] = L^{-1}[Y \setminus O]$, i.e. inverse images of closed sets of the reals.

Clearly $Y \subseteq L^{-1}[\{0\}]$ (a convergent series has the property that its summands convergence to $0$), which is closed, as $\{0\}$ is closed, and so $\overline{Y} \subseteq L^{-1}[\{0\}$.

If, on the other hand, we have any closed $C$ containing $Y$, so $Y \subseteq C$ where $C$ is closed, we know that $C= L^{-1}[D]$ where $D$ is closed in the reals. Hence $\{0\} = L[Y] \subseteq D$, so $0 \in D$ and hence $L^{-1}[\{0\}]\subseteq C$, so the set $L^{-1}[\{0\}$ is indeed the mimimal closed set that contains $Y$, hence by definition its closure.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{b_n\}\in Y$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=0.$

(I).   If $\{a_n\}\in X$ and $0\ne L=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ then $B_{L,L/2}$ is an open set which contains $\{a_n\}$ and is disjoint from $Y,$ so $\{a_n\}\not \in \overline Y.$

(II). If $\{a_n\}\in X$ and $0=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ let $U$ be any open set containing $\{a_n\}$. Then $\{a_n\}\in B_{L,e}\subset U$ for some $L\in \Bbb R$ and $0<e\in \Bbb R.$

Now $e>|L|$.( Otherwise $0\not \in (L-e,L+e)$, implying that no member of $B_{L,e}$ converges  to $0,$ but $\{a_n\}$ belongs to $B_{L,e}$ and it $does$ converge to $0.$)

So let $e^*=\min(|e+L|,|e-L|).$ Then $e^*>0$ and $$\{a_n\}\in B_{0,e^*} \subset B_{L,e}\subset U .$$ Since  $B_{0,r}\supset Y$ for every $r>0,$ we have $ U\cap Y\supset B_{0,e^*}\cap Y=Y \ne \phi$. So every open set $U$ containing $\{a_n\}$ intersects $Y,$ implying $\{a_n\}\in \overline Y.$

(III).  In summary, $\{a_n\}\in \overline Y$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0.$